# Rails 5.1 how to not list nulls in a collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a collection_select field listed here:

```
    <%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Document.order(:name), :id, :name,
    {:include_blank => ''}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
```

The name field has nulls in it for certain cases. I only want to list the name in the collection_select if it is not null.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a scope in your Document class:

```
##document.rb
scope :named_documents, -> { where.not(name: nil).order(:name) }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
 <%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Document.named_documents, :id, :name, {:include_blank => ''}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed to tweak it a bit because it was an empty string. This is what I ended up with that works. scope :named_documents, -> { where("name <> ''").order(:name) }

Comment: Don't you think this should be fixed by adding a NOT NULL constaint and a validation in the model?

Comment: No I'm using acts_as_tree and jstree to build a tree of a file manager. Sometimes the field will be empty if it is not a category header.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
<%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Document.named_documents.reject{|d| d.name.nil?}.order(:name), :id, :name,
    {:include_blank => ''}, {:class => 'form-control'} %>
```

I updated it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an undefined method "reject" error on that.